# ImportError: cannot import name 'Response' from 'pip._vendor.requests' (unknown location)

Tags: python, pip

I put "pip install scrapy-user-agents" on cmd, so I got this:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\duvan requena\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\duvan requena\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Duvan Requena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\duvan requena\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 69, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "c:\users\duvan requena\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 91, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\users\duvan requena\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\duvan requena\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import (
  File "c:\users\duvan requena\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import LinkCollector
  File "c:\users\duvan requena\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests import Response
ImportError: cannot import name 'Response' from 'pip._vendor.requests' (unknown location)
```

What should I do? I've been looking for the error but it doesn't seem like there would be people with the same problem

Comment: Can you try reinstalling pip?

Comment: Since the original importing the pip._vendor.requests isn't throwing an error, it looks like your error might be that the package was installed incorrectly. Ensure that you have the package installed - this likely means that the name and folder was downloaded without everything else (like saying you have IOS and it only shows a lock screen - no functionality). Try deleting and reinstalling the package, upgrading pip, and if that doesn't work, take a look into [homebrew](https://brew.sh) to try downloading it.